# Reading cookies in Javascript that is coming from app server

Tags: javascript, java, http, jsp, cookies

I am facing a problem with reading cookies .
my web url is say - abc.com . now there is one simple html login page in webserver. whenever i am submiting this login form it sends request in appserver  hosted in different machine,we have given complete appserver url in form action .now from app server we are setting cookie to read in html page . but here i am facing the issue .

cookie is getting saved but it is coming in other section please see the image(image 1) below mapped with appserver url, cookie-errorMessage is saved froma Appserver.
webserver url  does not  have this(errorMessage) cookie please see the (image 2) .

i am trying to read the cookie using document.cookie and it is reading cookie available in document (Please see the image 2) so i am not getting errorMessage saved by appserver.
I want to read cookie (i.e-errormessage) available in other section mapped with appserver url (please see the image 1) .
**Note** - both image is of same page just showing data of different section highlited in red

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: You know that cookies are not shared across domains, right?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes i know but here .cookie is available there only it is available in other section and my both app and webserver are mapped with same domain name

Comment: I don't know what that means, "other section". Are you cookies scoped to a specific path? It looks like they are, but the information is cut off in image 1.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen please see the highlighted section in image 1

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes it is scoped to different path

Comment: Then that's your problem.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen then wat is solution

Comment: Have your appserver set the cookie on the root path.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes .cookie.setPath("/");